# Why would the ttk widget only appears after there is a configuration change event and not when the button is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk

Can you help me understand why the `ttk.Checkbutton` widget does not appear after the `ttk.Button` widget is pressed? The `ttk.Checkbutton` widget would only appear when there is a configuration change event, for example after moving the sash of the `ttk.PanedWindow` widget or by resizing the root window. Or, when the height of `self.f2` is less than the Checkbutton. This code uses a [vertical scroll frame](https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/scrframe.py) which is saved in the file named `scrframe.py`

Test Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from scrframe import VerticalScrollFrame


class App(ttk.PanedWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, orient="vertical"):
        super().__init__(parent, orient=orient)
        self.parent = parent
        self.after_id = None
        
        self.f1 = ttk.Frame(self, style="Top.TFrame")
        self.f2 = VerticalScrollFrame(self, background='green')
        self.add(self.f1)
        self.add(self.f2)
        self.b1 = ttk.Button(self.f1, text="Button", command=self.load_image,
                             width=30)
        self.b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.f1.bind("<Configure>", self.schedule_event)
        self.f2.bind("<Configure>", self.schedule_event)
        self.bind("<<SashMoved>>", self.do_something)

    # Event handlers
    def schedule_event(self, event):
        if self.after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.after(500, self.event_generate, "<<SashMoved>>")

    def do_something(self, event):
        print("do_something was called")

    def load_image(self):
        im = '/home/user/Pictures/image.jpeg'
        im = Image.open(im)
        im.thumbnail((200, 200))
        self.thumbnail = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        self.thumbnail.image = im
        self.cb = ttk.Checkbutton(self.f2.interior, text="Image",
                                  image=self.thumbnail, compound="top")
        self.cb.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.update_idletasks()  # Does not work
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ss = ttk.Style()
    ss.configure('Top.TFrame', background="red")
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Issue: Checkbutton does not appears immediately when the height of `self.f2` is greater than the Checkbutton.

[image: Issue]

Checkbutton appears immediately when the height of `self.f2` is less than the Checkbutton:

[image: Checkbutton appears immediately when the height of self.f2 is less than the Checkbutton]

Comment: On Python 3.11 on Windows 10, the image and checkbox show immediately when the button is pressed.

Comment: @BoppreH Thanks for letting me know. I am using Linux os.

Comment: @BoppreH I have updated the [scrframe.py](https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/scrframe.py) file to what I had used. Can you let me know if Python 3.11 on Windows 10 experiences the issue mentioned in my question?

Comment: Why don't you use `event.width` and `event.height` instead of those `.winfo_reqwidth()` and `.winfo_reqheight()` in those `<Configure>` event callbacks?

Comment: @acw1668 Are you referring to the callbacks in `scrframe.py`? `w.winfo_reqheight()` _These methods return the requested height of widget w. This is the minimum height necessary so that all of w's contents have the room they need. The actual height may be different due to negotiations with the geometry manager._

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried to print out the result of `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()` in those callbacks to see whether they are what you want actually?

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks. :) Looks like the issue stems from the `._configure_canvas` event handler not using `event.width` but  `canvas.winfo_reqwidth()`. The correct syntax looks to be `canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=event.width)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Simply using `event,width` is not a robust solution. It causes another issue. I have updated my answer with the width that I think should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by @acw1668. It looks like the issue stems from the `._configure_canvas` event handler in [scrframe.py](https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/scrframe.py) simply using `canvas.winfo_reqwidth()`. Below are printed-out values after the Button is released:

```
def _configure_interior(event):
interior.winfo_reqwidth()=228 interior.winfo_reqheight()=165
canvas.winfo_reqwidth()=1 canvas.winfo_reqheight()=223
event.width=261 event.height=165
do_something was called
```

They showed that previously the width of the ["canvas window objected"](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_window.html) that contained `self.interior` (a `ttk.Frame` widget) was mistakenly set to 1 pixels width since `canvas.winfo_reqwidth()=1` hence the `ttk.Checkbutton` widget was hidden.

After further testing, I discovered that simply using `event.width` is not a robust solution. In the situation when the `Tk` window width is less than the width of the Checkbutton, the appearance of the Checkbutton will be truncated when the Canvas is scrolled horizontally.

Hence, the correct width to use for the  "canvas window objected" should instead be the max of `canvas.winfo_reqwidth()` and `event.width`.

```
def _configure_canvas(event):
    print(f"\ndef _configure_canvas(event):")
    print(f"{interior.winfo_reqwidth()=} {interior.winfo_reqheight()=}")
    print(f"{canvas.winfo_reqwidth()=} {canvas.winfo_reqheight()=}")
    print(f"{event.width=} {event.height=}")
    if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
        # update the canvas window object's width to the max of canvas.winfo_reqwidth() and event.width
        maxwidth = max([canvas.winfo_reqwidth(), event.width])
        canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=maxwidth)
```

Outcome from using `event.width`:

[image: eventwidth]

Outcome from using `max([canvas.winfo_reqwidth(), event.width])`:
[image: maxwidth]